# Проблема с качеством, полученных фото

Tags: java, android, android-studio, камера, android-camera

Есть код для камеры, на одних устройствах фотографии сохраняются в хорошем качестве (1920х1080), а на других устройствах хуже, чем в превью. Кто сталкивался с таким? Какие могут быть варианты решения?
Класс1:

```
package com.barrslol.camera1_2;


 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
 import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.hardware.Camera;
  import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
  import android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback;
  import android.net.Uri;
 import android.os.AsyncTask;
 import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
  import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.SurfaceView;
  import android.view.View;
   import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
  import android.view.View.OnLongClickListener;
  import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
 import android.view.Window;
 import android.view.WindowManager;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.FrameLayout;
 import android.widget.Toast;

public class CamTestActivity extends Activity {
private static final String TAG = "CamTestActivity";
Preview preview;
Button buttonClick;
Camera camera;
Activity act;
Context ctx;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ctx = this;
    act = this;
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    preview = new Preview(this, (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surfaceView));
    preview.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    ((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout)).addView(preview);
    preview.setKeepScreenOn(true);

    preview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
        }
    });

    Toast.makeText(ctx, getString(R.string.take_photo_help), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    int numCams = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
    if(numCams > 0){
        try{
            camera = Camera.open(0);
            camera.startPreview();
            preview.setCamera(camera);
        } catch (RuntimeException ex){
            Toast.makeText(ctx, getString(R.string.camera_not_found), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if(camera != null) {
        camera.stopPreview();
        preview.setCamera(null);
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }
    super.onPause();
}

private void resetCam() {
    camera.startPreview();
    preview.setCamera(camera);
}

private void refreshGallery(File file) {
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));
    sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}

ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {
    public void onShutter() {
        //           Log.d(TAG, "onShutter'd");
    }
};

PictureCallback rawCallback = new PictureCallback() {
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        //           Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - raw");
    }
};

PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        new SaveImageTask().execute(data);
        resetCam();
        Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - jpeg");
    }
};

private class SaveImageTask extends AsyncTask<byte[], Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(byte[]... data) {
        FileOutputStream outStream = null;

        // Write to SD Card
        try {
            File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/camtest");
            dir.mkdirs();               

            String fileName = String.format("%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis());
            File outFile = new File(dir, fileName);

            outStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
            outStream.write(data[0]);
            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();

            Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: " + data.length + " to " + outFile.getAbsolutePath());

            refreshGallery(outFile);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        }
        return null;
    }

}
}
```

И 2 класс:

```
package com.barrslol.camera1_2;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Size;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;






class Preview extends ViewGroup implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
private final String TAG = "Preview";

SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
SurfaceHolder mHolder;
Size mPreviewSize;
List<Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes;
Camera mCamera;

Preview(Context context, SurfaceView sv) {
    super(context);

    mSurfaceView = sv;
  //addView(mSurfaceView);

    mHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}

public void setCamera(Camera camera) {
    mCamera = camera;
    if (mCamera != null) {
        mSupportedPreviewSizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        requestLayout();

        // get Camera parameters
        Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();

        List<String> focusModes = params.getSupportedFocusModes();
        if (focusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO)) {
            // set the focus mode
            params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
            // set Camera parameters
            mCamera.setParameters(params);
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    // We purposely disregard child measurements because act as a
    // wrapper to a SurfaceView that centers the camera preview instead
    // of stretching it.
    final int width = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
    final int height = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);

    if (mSupportedPreviewSizes != null) {
        mPreviewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes, width, height);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    if (changed && getChildCount() > 0) {
        final View child = getChildAt(0);

        final int width = r - l;
        final int height = b - t;

        int previewWidth = width;
        int previewHeight = height;
        if (mPreviewSize != null) {
            previewWidth = mPreviewSize.width;
            previewHeight = mPreviewSize.height;
        }

        // Center the child SurfaceView within the parent.
        if (width * previewHeight > height * previewWidth) {
            final int scaledChildWidth = previewWidth * height / previewHeight;
            child.layout((width - scaledChildWidth) / 2, 0,
                    (width + scaledChildWidth) / 2, height);
        } else {
            final int scaledChildHeight = previewHeight * width / previewWidth;
            child.layout(0, (height - scaledChildHeight) / 2,
                    width, (height + scaledChildHeight) / 2);
        }
    }
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // The Surface has been created, acquire the camera and tell it where
    // to draw.
    try {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        }
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        Log.e(TAG, "IOException caused by setPreviewDisplay()", exception);
    }
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // Surface will be destroyed when we return, so stop the preview.
    if (mCamera != null) {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
    }
}


private Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
    final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
    double targetRatio = (double) w / h;
    if (sizes == null) return null;

    Size optimalSize = null;
    double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

    int targetHeight = h;

    // Try to find an size match aspect ratio and size
    for (Size size : sizes) {
        double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
        if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE) continue;
        if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
            optimalSize = size;
            minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
        }
    }

    // Cannot find the one match the aspect ratio, ignore the requirement
    if (optimalSize == null) {
        minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        for (Size size : sizes) {
            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }
    }
    return optimalSize;
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
    if(mCamera != null) {
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
        requestLayout();

        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    }
}
```

}

Разметка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- Button
    android:id="@+id/btnCapture"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/round_button"
    android:text="@string/btn_capture" /-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По аналогии с `getSupportedPreviewSizes()` есть метод [`getSupportedPictureSizes()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedPictureSizes()), который отвечает за разрешение *при съёмке*. Выберите нужный Вам размер из списка, полученного от `getSupportedPictureSizes()` и установите его для камеры с помощью `camera.getParameters().setPictureSize(newSize.width, newSize.height)`.

Только не пытайтесь взять первый или последний элемент из списка в качестве самого лучшего или худшего качества съёмки. В своё время я столкнулся с тем, что на некоторых девайсах `getSupportedPictureSizes()` выдаёт список, отсортированный от самого большого разрешения к самому низкому, а на некоторых наоборот.

Comment: Входе поиска решения этой проблемы, тоже пришел к этой мысли.
Спасибо!